# Why is the book of תהילים not called תהילות?

Tags: hebrew

If the word תהילה is feminine why don't we call the book of תהילים not תהילות?

Comment: We do. (At least, depending who "we" is)

Comment: Please can you give an example?

Comment: See Ibn Ezra's conclusion to the book (available on Sefaria)